# Can rude comments that were removed be accessed later on?

Tags: discussion, offensive, deleted-comments

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851788/is-there-any-working-webcam-for-wpf) I told a user that his question was off-topic; which triggered a really nasty reply by him. I flagged "rude" immediately (which is perfectly fine - it was rude); but now I kinda regret ... to not have taken at least a screen shot for my private "chamber of different experiences" made on SO.

I understand that moderators can see deleted comments; but I guess for "normal" users that content is "gone for good"?

To be more precise: actually I have no intent to "bring back" the flagged comment. I am simply wondering if there is any way to "see" what it said in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am simply wondering if there is any way to "see" what it said in any way

No, there is no way unless you become a moderator on the site.

The question is: why you want to see it again? If your only intention is to "save a screenshot" that's kind of pointless, since moderators can still see the comment, so in case of repeated offense, it can be used against the user. No need for screenshots.

If you think you made a mistake and the comment **wasn't rude** then you can flag the post itself, choose "Other" and ask a moderator to  take a second look and if they deem it OK, undelete it.

Comment: Right; I am actually not talking about "bringing back"; more like "seeing again". Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Fair enough, edited the answer to fit.

Comment: Note that moderators can only undelete comments deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Adam oh, wasn't aware of that. Why is it like this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard IIRC it was never intended to be an undeletion tool so much as an "undo" for accidentally deleting a comment and/or enable the "purge all comments on a post, selectively undelete the handful worth keeping" type of workflow.

Answer (score 9):

> I understand that moderators can see deleted comments; but I guess for "normal" users that content is "gone for good"?

Correct.

Moderators *can* bring back deleted comments, but only for extraordinary reasons (and "I want a screen shot for my collection" does not fall under that category).

This can be used when moderators delete all comments in a thread (in one action), but want to restore a selected few (this is sometimes easier than cherry picking what to delete).